# Beamer multilingual template: custom command white spaces problem

Tags: beamer, bold

I have a problem with the following custom command on [beamer multilingual template](https://gitlab.com/erotavlas/beamer-multilingual-template).

```
\newcommand{\boldlang}[2]{\lang{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\boldlang{it}{Text} \boldlang{en}{Text}
```

The output has added white spaces that are not present by using:

```
\textbf{Text}
```

You can download the project on gitlab as MWE. Is there any way to avoid to add white spaces when using multiple languages?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You can download it from https://gitlab.com/erotavlas/beamer-multilingual-template. Slides 3-4. Have I to copy and paste all the code here? There are many files.

Comment: You can trim the code down to the minimum you need to reproduce the error, but it is important that the question is self-sustained and does not rely on external resources which at some point might no longer be available which would make your question useless for future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer has nothing to do with this. It's a problem with `multilanguage.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{multilanguage}[2015/10/04 Create a document in one of multiple languages]

% ... comments omitted ...

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\setdoclang}[2]
{% <--- missing
    \main@language{#2}% <--- missing
    \def\doclang{#2}% <--- missing
    \def\doclangshort{#1}% <--- missing
}

% set short and long language codes, the second one must be known by babel
\setdoclang{en}{english}
%\setdoclang{it}{italian}

%
% Multilingual support commands
%
\newcommand{\langif}[3]
{% <--- missing
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\doclang} \OR \equal{#1}{\doclangshort}}
        {#2}
        {#3}% <--- missing
}

\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\langif{#1}{#2}{}}
\newcommand{\sectionlang}[2]{\lang{#1}{\section{#2}}}
\newcommand{\subsectionlang}[2]{\lang{#1}{\subsection{#2}}}
\newcommand{\subsubsectionlang}[2]{\lang{#1}{\subsubsection{#2}}}

\newcommand{\frametitlelang}[2]{\lang{#1}{{#2}}}

\newcommand{\boldlang}[2]{\lang{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
```

The string `% <--- missing` shows where a `%` is missing in the package code.

As the code is originally written, each use of `\langif`, so also of `\lang`, will add two spaces.

Protecting the end-of-lines in `\setdoclang` is not really needed, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Besides, you should type

```
\boldlang{it}{Text}\boldlang{en}{Text}
```

with no space between the alternatives, otherwise the space would be typeset.

Comment: You are right. By adding your suggestion the white spaces are reduced, but there is still a white space in excess.

Comment: @user54865 If you write `\lang{it}{x} \lang{en}{y}` there *is* a space in between notwithstanding the text is not printed. Don't use a space.

Comment: You are right, it was trivial.